# Docusign connect .net listener returns empty data

Tags: docusignapi

I'm new to DocuSign Connect and I'm trying to code a listener for events. Currently, 
i'm using code from .net SDK connect listener sample, but could notice Request.InputStream in below code always is NULL, though from the connect logs could notice the POST is complete.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[Request.InputStream.Length];
Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\EnvelopeCerts"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\EnvelopeCerts");
if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Documents"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Documents");
```

The problem is that nothing comes out of it, or is empty. I know that information is passed via POST, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How are you testing? If you're using DocuSign to test, what environment are you using? Are you using HTTPS or a local dev box?

Comment: This is a Docusign demo environment, and i'm using HTTP to port 80 hosted on my local dev box, with a publicly accessible URL.Did initiate events using 'Publish Xml' option.  

    public partial class Receiver : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

The code i'm using is from Docusign SDK MS.NET Connect sample with url 'http://<your_server>/HCC/Receiver.aspx'

Comment: Have you read the [DocuSign Connect guide](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/connect-guide.pdf) to make sure you've got everything setup right?  I would double check to make sure your Connect settings are all configured correctly, try re-publishing (re-sending) the updates through the logs screen, or test with multiple envelopes.  Also you're positive your URL is publicly accessible right?

Comment: Honestly before putting DocuSign into the loop, I would use POSTMAN or some other API tool to send information to your local box. I just setup the SDK on my local box and sent through Postman and `Request.InputStream` and I see `Length = 2851` which is what I was expecting from the sample XML that I sent through.

Comment: The URL and settings are as per the Connect guide, and below is a sample response from Connect logs, which says successful with 'Done!' status returned, but still see empty Request.InputStream.

<body> <form name="form1" method="post" action="receiver.aspx" id="form1">  <div> <span id="statusLabel">Done!</span> </div> </form> </body>

Also, from logs screen, event notifications are sporadically failing, is this expected with demo environment?

Comment: You have to setup your application to allow event notifications through reg in server 2012, so it depends on your environment. I still advise troubleshooting with POSTMAN or SoapUI or something so you can actually see data full circle.

Comment: I have verified using POSTMAN, and could see the data i have sent with length, any further tests i can try to troubleshoot this?

Also, from logs screen, event notifications are sporadically failing, is this expected using Docusign demo environment?

Comment: DocuSign demo environment is constantly being updated with new code and features, so yes sometimes demo is a little unstable and you'll see some issues.  These are almost never present in production though and DocuSign engineering usually resolves such issues very quickly...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Connect Settings? (you can remove the URL if you'd like)

Comment: [These are my settings configured](http://i.imgur.com/T4CRyhn.png?1)

Comment: Are you handling the X.509 certificate properly? I'd take that our while testing.